# Android Messages how to create a custom notification

Tags: android, notification, notification-area, customizer

I have mental disability.  Is there a way to create a custom notification for Android Messages where the Ubuntu screen shakes/flashes or does something to get my attention when my phone can't vibrate like normal to get my attention.  Example the Android Messages Desktop program is minimized or covered up by my browser and I cant hear the sound notification set to alert me that I have a new message?  If phone vibrates in my pocket no problem.  Can I create a custom notification in Ubuntu with something that shakes the display or does something strange that tell me to check the window to see the message?  My memory problems needs my phone 24/7 but 5 feet away might as well be 5 hundred feet! Thank you so much for ideas people!!  Sounds silly to you, but critical for me.

Comment: maybe this here can help you https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/integrate-your-android-phone-with-gnome.html

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/

Comment: kannzzmm2: gsonnect i will try. Thank you.  I wanna modify ubuntu notification practices to my style.  Some programs we use have better notifications than others.  Wanna learn how to modify notifications already created.  Ex. I love my phone vibrates when I get a message.  Something clever like that will help me.  make sense??

Comment: kannzzmm2:  i have mental disability from car crash. Used to be smarter than now.  Now I have to really fu*&kin work for it!!! lol  I call it adapting instead of complaining!!! lmao I will check back often for ideas to create or modify existing notifications in software.  I love ANDROID MESSAGES for just that, MESSAGES.  pushbullet is awesome for those who havent heard of it for lots of stuff uses chrome/chromium extensions as well as mozilla, opera etc..